# matplotlib: plot or scatter without line through marker

Tags: matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot, markers, linestyle

is there a simple way to have `scatter()` plots (or just `plot`s) with data points shown by some marker and connected by lines, but, when `markerfacecolor='none'` (or `facecolor=none`) have the line not shown within the area of the marker.

E.g.:

```
xx = arange(0.0,10.0,0.5)
yy = sin(xx)
plt.plot(xx,yy,'k-',marker='o',markerfacecolor='none')
```

results in the following figure.

[image]

But I would like the lines connecting data points to start not from the center of each marker but from its borders.

Comment: is there a reason you can't just make the `markerfacecolor = 'white'`?

Comment: @tom yes: this plot will be superimposed on some image in the background and the marker needs to be transparent (except for its edge) so as not to cover the pixels of the image.

Comment: This is possible, but I do not think it is easy.  The problem is that you need to know the size of the markers in pixel space, but specify everything else about the line in data-space and you do not know the conversion between the two until pretty late in the draw process.  Maybe drawing each marker as it's own path and using it to clip the line is the easiest path?  I suggest sending this as an email to matplotlib-users@python.org as this is an interesting use case.

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks! I read your comment just now. I will mailbox them!